# Как повернуть содержимое файла Haskell

Tags: haskell

Нужно повернуть содержимое текстового файла на n градусов(содержимое может быть представлено любыми символами)
Сделал поворот матрицы на 90 влево и вправо

```
import Data.List

rotateLeft :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rotateLeft = reverse . transpose

rotateRight :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rotateRight = transpose . reverse
```

Но вот с углами не кратными 90 вообще придумать ничего не могу.Да и эта матрица только числа принимает
Со считыванием матрицы из файла немного накидал,но тоже не то

```
import System.IO
import System.Environment
main = do
[fileName] <- getArgs
fileSource <- readFile fileName
let fileMatrix = map (\x -> map (\i -> (read i) :: Int) $ words x) $ lines
```

Он выдает ошибку

Помогите,добрые люди студенту.У нас по ФП вообще 0 методичек,делаем все задания на ощупь.Вожусь с этой задачей уже 2 неделю.Заранее спасибо

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легкого способа не ищите, принцип такой же, как у поворота растрового изображения

```hs
image :: [[Char]]
image =
  [ "TTTTTTTT EEEEEEEE  SSSSSS  SSSSSSSS"
  , "   TT    EE       SS    SS    SS   "
  , "   TT    EE       SS          SS   "
  , "   TT    EEEEEE    SSSSSS     SS   "
  , "   TT    EE             SS    SS   "
  , "   TT    EE       SS    SS    SS   "
  , "   TT    EEEEEEEE  SSSSSS     SS   "
  ]

getPixel :: [[Char]] -> Int -> Int -> Char
getPixel img x y
  | x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height = img !! y !! x
  | otherwise = ' '
  where
    height = length img
    width = length $ head img

rotate :: Double -> (Double, Double) -> (Double, Double)
rotate a (x, y) = (x * cos a + y * sin a, -x * sin a + y * cos a)

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ putStrLn $ do
  y <- [0 .. 30]
  return $ do
    x <- [0 .. 40]
    let (x', y') = rotate (pi / 4) (x - 5, y - 2)
    return $ getPixel image (floor x') (floor y')
```

```
     T
     TT
      TT
       TT
      TTTT
     TTT TT
    TTT   T
   TTT     EE
    T     EEEE
         EEE EE
        EEE   EE
       EEE E   EE
        E   E   EE
         E   E
          E      SSS
           E    SSSSS
            E   SS  SS
              S  S   SS
              SS  S  SS
               S   S  S
                S  SS   SS
                 SSSS    SS
                  SS      SS
                         SSSS
                        SSS SS
                       SSS   S
                      SSS
                       S
```

С квадратным шрифтом такого искажения не будет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]